# Could Lobot ever know love?

Tags: star-wars

Could Lobot of Cloud City in Empire Strikes Back be capable of love? Or would his implants preclude such emotion?

Comment: It's not a great question, but I don't think it's that bad

Answer (score 7):

[Lobot](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lobot) is a human with cybernetic implants.

Prior to his implants, he could definitely know love. Afterwards, he experienced a sort of loss of humanity, but was not necessarily incapable.

Per Wookieepedia:

> Lobot's new cybernetic implants increased his intelligence dramatically. He could communicate with the city's central computer at all times, controlling issues of bureaucracy, law enforcement, computer programming, repair and security, as well as the communication systems, repulsorlifts, and life-support systems. In many ways, Lobot was Cloud City—he was the true power behind its everyday operations, whereas the Baron Administrator served that role to the public's face. In the past, running the city's computer would take dozens of specialists. Now, Lobot could fulfill the duties of many instantly.
>
> The only negative side effect was that his speech centers deteriorated under the neural pathways to his brain. While he still retained the ability to speak, his speech was reduced to minimal, infrequent sentences. Regardless, he rarely felt the need to speak, for he could fulfill his duties without the need for verbal communication. His observations of the world came to focus on numbers and formulas. His loss of humanity seemed strange only to those who did not know him.

Comment: So much history and tragedy in that brave little man.

Comment: @Gelfamat - tragedy? He was an up-and-rising **slaver**, like his father before him; and later a thief. His implants were a trade-off for 15 year prison sentence.

Comment: Lobot also certainly knows friendship; he and Lando are good friends, and his speech apparatus never erodes to the point that the two cannot speak. In *Before the Storm*, it is implied that Lando is the only person with whom Lobot regularly speaks, but it is also stated that Lobot enjoys white-water rafting; the man is clearly capable of complex emotions, he just doesn't show them.

Comment: Wow, never knew the slaver back-story. I did know that borg-implants were used as a form of punishment, but assumed Lobot was an exception, not the rule.

Comment: DVK: Sorry Comic Book Guy, I didn't read the Lobot biography or every word ever written about him canon/non canon, etc. Some people just enjoy things without obsessing about them to that extent.

Answer (score 4):

According to *The New Essential Guide to Characters (2002)*:

- On one hand, Lobot was definitely able to experience friendship and loyalty.

  > Lobot and Calrissian became friends
- On the other hand, his emotional capacity was "eroded":

  > ... it also eroded his emotional and linguistic centers

It's impossible to answer a subjective question of "Could Lobot ever know love?" since "love" isn't really defined very well. The answer isn't a clear "no" in a sense of his emotional centers were specifically "eroded" and not "destroyed" - AND he's shown to have capacity for friendship and attachment; and it's also not a clear "yes" since none of the canon works I'm aware of listed him actually being in love or having an opportunity to.